# How to change channels in audio (from BOTH to LEFT) without re-encoding/conversion?

Tags: multichannel, ffmpeg

lets say I have very long audio file, and I want to remove only right channel from BOTH (stereo) channels. 
Can that be done without re-encoding, just simply switching off one channel? (maybe FFMPEG??)

Comment: Not possible with ffmpeg.

Comment: Are they stereo files? What do you mean "BOTH" channels? By definition anything that is right channel will not be in the left already.

Comment: @Timinycricket yes, stereo. I hear voice only in left speaker/headphone.

Comment: what is the encodng of the source files ?

Comment: @audionuma does it matter? maybe aac (or ac3), possible also mp3.

Comment: Yes, it does matter as this can be done without loss with lossless codecs, not with lossy codecs, although decoding/encoding might be required. This is not possible with aac, ac3 or mp3 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this could be done without batch conversion. What you could do is load all the files into a batch converter and have them run through an effect or process that would produce the desired result, either by panning everything hard left in such a way that the right channel's content was eliminated or by panning the left channel's content to the centre and reducing the volume of the right channel to -inf. There are plug-ins that will do either.

Depending on the batch converter you use, you could replace the individual files or create copies with the channel conversion process applied.

Of course, depending on what you want these files for, you could also set the balance of a media player all the way left when you play the files or have your DAW/editor  do it when you load the files into it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: let's forget batch conversion. For single file I stil ahve to use like AudaCity or CuBase?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Audacity, but I'm sure that the programs you mention will allow the use of the processes I referred to in my answer so you could perform the channel conversions one file at a time as needed, either replacing the content in the right channel by duplicating that on the left or by panning everything all the way left with a stereo balance pan mode depending on the exact result you're looking to achieve.